# Exibir relatório de tabelas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, relatório

Estou com um problema ao gerar um relatório, no qual o administrador do site verá os campos `ID` e `login` de todos os usuários cadastrados, até o momento, tenho este código:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$emite = "SELECT ID, login FROM usuarios";
$exibe = mysql_query($emite);
if ($exibe-> num_rows > '0') {
     while($row = $exibe->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["ID"]. " - login: ". $row["login"]. "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 resultados";
}
?>
```

Até aí tudo bem, o problema ocorre na hora de executar, o qual retorna um erro:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object "localarquivo" on line 9

E honestamente, não entendi o motivo deste erro nem como consertá-lo.

Comment: leitura recomendada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/13561

Comment: o que é `localarquivo` e qual é a linha 9?

Comment: "Localarquivo" é o diretório no qual meu sistema está localizado, optei por não mostrá-lo.
@JorgeB.

Comment: Linha 9 é a linha
`while($row = $exibe->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: Acontece que estas a misturar [mysql_](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) e [mysqli_](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Só com a nova versão de `mysqli_` é que podes usar como objeto `$exibe->fetch_assoc()`. Com `mysql_` só podes usar `mysql_fetch_assoc($exibe)`. Aconselho-te a mudar tudo para `mysqli_`, para mais informações lê o link do Sanção.

Comment: Na hipótese de mudar de mysql (em depreciação) para mysqli, pense em dar uma olhada em PDO (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MySQL* não suporta o estilo orientado a objectos, e no teu script há pelo menos duas referências à métodos de classes.

Nesta alínea, para além da referência no estilo orientado, o `0` é passado como *string* diante de um operador de comparação quantitativa. O exemplo vai funcionar, mas é sempre melhor tratar de um inteiro como um inteiro.

De:

```
$exibe-> num_rows > '0'
```

Para:

```
mysql_num_rows($exibe) > 0
```

Aqui foi a mesma coisa, referência a métodos de uma classe que nem sequer existe.

De:

```
$row = $exibe->fetch_assoc()
```

Para:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exibe)
```

As funções geram erros, para métodos chamados à partir de variáveis que não são objectos. No caso, retornou um *E_NOTICE*

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object "localarquivo" on line 9

Vamos também supôr, que no teu ficheiro config.php` estejam as variáveis de conexão, e também onde selecionas o banco de dados, visto que estás a usar *MySQL*.

```
...

$emite = "SELECT ID, login FROM usuarios";

$exibe = mysql_query($emite);
if (mysql_num_rows($exibe) > 0) {
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exibe)) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["ID"]. " - login: ". $row["login"]. "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 resultados";
}
```

Outra coisa, é que as funções *MySQL* estão obsoletas, dando então lugar as novas e mais seguras funções do *MySQLi* que é uma versão do velho *MySQL*, mas mais segura, ou podes usar também o *PDO*.

Podes também ver neste exemplo, como ficaria o teu script, com o *MySQLi*:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco_de_dados");

$emite = "SELECT ID, login FROM usuarios";

$exibe = mysqli_query($conexao, $emite);
if (mysqli_num_rows($exibe) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exibe)) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - login: ". $row["login"]. "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 resultados";
}
```

---

**Algumas Referẽncias:**

- [MySQLi - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PDO - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Existem também muitas boas respostas acerca do *MySQLi* e o *PDO* aqui no *SOpt*, basta que os procures usando a barra de busca do [site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com#search).